# How to delete an entire object based on elements in an array which is nested inside another array of objects in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am pretty new to MongoDB. This the structure of my database **hospital** and collection `patientData`.

when I do

```
db.patientData.find().pretty()
```

I get

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6086fbc54f25d8cf518e99c3"),
    "first name" : "olivia",
    "last name" : "jackson",
    "age" : 24,
    "history" : [
        {
            "disease" : "conjectivitus",
            "treatment" : "eyedrops"
        },
        {
            "symptoms" : [
                "eye scratching",
                "sore throat",
                "headache",
                "jointpain"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6086fbc54f25d8cf518e99c4"),
    "first name" : "Doriya",
    "last name" : "Xavier",
    "age" : 27,
    "history" : [
        {
            "disease" : "para thyroid",
            "treatment" : "thyroxin"
        },
        {
            "symptoms" : [
                "bulginess",
                "sore throat",
                "headache",
                "jointpain"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6086fbc54f25d8cf518e99c5"),
    "first name" : "Meenu",
    "last name" : "Danish",
    "age" : 32,
    "history" : [
        {
            "disease" : "chicken pox",
            "treatment" : "citricin"
        },
        {
            "symptoms" : [
                "itchiness",
                "pimple",
                "fever",
                "nausea"
            ]
        }
```

I want to delete the objects based on the symptoms of ***"headache"***. Which is a pure array.

Basicaly next time when I do,

```
db.patientData.find().pretty()
```

I only want to get this document in my collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6086fbc54f25d8cf518e99c5"),
    "first name" : "Meenu",
    "last name" : "Danish",
    "age" : 32,
    "history" : [
        {
            "disease" : "chicken pox",
            "treatment" : "citricin"
        },
        {
            "symptoms" : [
                "itchiness",
                "pimple",
                "fever",
                "nausea"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using `$pull` but it is not working.

Please help me with the code.

Comment: just need to do query in delete `.remove({ "history.symptoms": "headache" })` it will remove documents that have `headache`, make sure you have backup of your database if you are not doing testing.

Comment: Thanks, man it worked. It is a testing DB. can we do something using the `.deleteMany()` command?

Comment: yes you can use `deleteMany()` as well.